# What is the equivalent of "DatabaseHandle" in firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am converting the Firebase Realtime database functions to Firestore Database, I am not able to get the equivalent for "DatabaseHandle" as in the below code to configure the database, I need to convert the database for the chat application , this is the tutorial I have been following [tutorial reference](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#7)!

```
fileprivate var _refHandle: DatabaseHandle?
  deinit {
    if let refHandle = _refHandle  {
      self.ref.child("messages").removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
    }
  }

  func configureDatabase() {
    //ref = Firestore.firestore()    // Listen for new messages in the Firebase database
    _refHandle = self.ref.collection("messages").observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) -> Void in
      guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
      strongSelf.messages.append(snapshot)
      strongSelf.clientTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: strongSelf.messages.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lot of differences in both the database but you can find most of the similarities. Like DatabaseHandle is equivalent to "[CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/CollectionReference)" and observer's are equivalent to "[Listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)".

Rather than following any code, you must refer to official documentation which has a snippet for all features and then you will able to make the difference.

Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Thanks, Sohil for your precious guidance